# Computing gradients of distribution parameters in tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-probability

I have a model that produces parameters for a beta distribution and would like to optimize according to some loss involving the pdf and the cdf of this distribution. However, I recently found that tensorflow's autograd routines are not producing the full gradients as I expected.

Before getting into the details of the example, the TL;DR question is: **how can I compute gradients of tensorflow probability distributions with respect to their hyperparameters, e.g., `alpha` and `beta` in a beta distribution?**

By way of example consider the following simple model (note this was thrown together to illustrate the code, the model itself doesn't make much sense). The model takes 3-dimensional data and produces 2-dimensional outputs. These outputs are shifted and viewed as `alpha` and `beta` in a beta distribution. For illustrative purposes I generate some data and aim to maximize the average probability. The following code produces some gradients:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

# a dummy model that will take in 3-dimensional data and output 2-dimensional data
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu'))

# data to feed into the model
input_data = tensorflow.random.normal((32,3))
# data to evaluate the distributions on
dist_data = tensorflow.random.uniform((32,1))/2.0+0.25

with tensorflow.GradientTape() as tape:
  # generate beta distributions from output of the network
  output = model(input_data)
  alpha = output[:,0,None]+1
  beta = output[:,1,None]+1
  dists = tfp.distributions.Beta(alpha,beta)

  # compute average probabilty
  dist_output = tensorflow.reduce_mean(dists.prob(dist_data))
grads = tape.gradient(dist_output,model.trainable_variables)
print(grads)
```

**Output**

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.02362663,  0.05741577],
       [ 0.02077126,  0.03589955],
       [ 0.04922515, -0.0180204 ]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.01512624, 0.08244684], dtype=float32)>]
```

Now if I instead target the CDF rather than the PDF I get `None` for gradients:

```
with tensorflow.GradientTape() as tape:
  # generate beta distributions from output of the network
  output = model(input_data)
  alpha = output[:,0,None]+1
  beta = output[:,1,None]+1
  dists = tfp.distributions.Beta(alpha,beta)

  # compute average cdf
  dist_output = tensorflow.reduce_mean(dists.cdf(dist_data))
grads = tape.gradient(dist_output,model.trainable_variables)
print(grads)
```

**Output**

```
[None, None]
```

I went to the underlying `tensorflow_probability` code and it appears that `tensorflow_probability` uses `betainc` from `tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops` and that the gradients are not evaluated there. This can be seen by replacing the CDF above with a direct all to the incomplete beta function (grads still return `None`).

```
with tensorflow.GradientTape() as tape:
  # generate beta distributions from output of the network
  output = model(input_data)
  alpha = output[:,0,None]+1
  beta = output[:,1,None]+1
  # compute average cdf
  dist_output = tensorflow.reduce_mean(tensorflow.math.betainc(alpha,beta,dist_data))
grads = tape.gradient(dist_output,model.trainable_variables)
print(grads)
```

**Output**

```
[None, None]
```

Similarly, the PDF code above calls `lbeta` which also doesn't seem to be considered by the gradient, though in this case `0` is returned instead of `None`

```
with tensorflow.GradientTape() as tape:
  # generate beta distributions from output of the network
  output = model(input_data)
  alpha = output[:,0,None]+1
  beta = output[:,1,None]+1

  # compute average probabilty
  norm_output = tensorflow.reduce_mean(tensorflow.math.lbeta(alpha,beta))
  
norm_grads = tape.gradient(norm_output,model.trainable_variables)
print(norm_grads)
```

Output

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

The net result of this is that if we have a complicated objective function involving both the PDF and the CDF, then we get non-zero gradients, but they are not correct as certain terms are not differentiated.

*Question:* **What are my options for computing these gradients in the `tensorflow` framework?**

Comment: TFP Beta samples are reparameterized so they are pathwise differentiable. With that in mind, AFAIK, CDF is not pathwise differentiable. That's why they are `None`.

Answer (score 0):

For posteriority: This works now in tensorflow.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should convert your answer in a comment 'couse it isn't **really answer** the question.